# AngularFire/Firebase Simple Login: how to setup login resolver on controller?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebasesimplelogin

I'm using AngularJS with UI Router along with Firebase/AngularFire.

I was able to implement Firebase's Simple Login with Facebook, Twitter, and Google+ within a controller based on their example in the docs; however, as I think about the scalability of my code I would like to abstract this login logic out of my controller and into a factory or service so that it is able to resolve properly on my controller in UI Router. The resolving is really important because I obviously don't want to show logged-in content to a logged-out user.

I've seen a number of implementations that sort of address this issue, but nothing seems to completely solve what I'm looking to achieve for the three social logins mentioned above. How could I further expand upon this with the code I currently have or rewrite a more suitable solution?

```
// Auth Service
// auth.js
APP.service('authService', ['$rootScope', 'endpoints', 

function($rootScope, endpoints) {

    var ref = new Firebase(endpoints.firebaseReference);

    this.auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(ref, function(error, user) {
        if (user) {
            $rootScope.$emit("login", user);
        } else if (error) {
            $rootScope.$emit("loginError", error);
        } else {
            $rootScope.$emit("logout");
        }   
    });

}

]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase + Angular guide has examples using simple login with routers under the [authentication section](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/bindings/angular/guide.html#section-angular-authentication)

ngRoute:

```
app.config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when("/home", {
    controller: "HomeCtrl",
    templateUrl: "views/home.html",
    resolve: {
      // controller will not be invoked until getCurrentUser resolves
      "currentUser": ["simpleLogin", function(simpleLogin) {
        // simpleLogin refers to our $firebaseSimpleLogin wrapper in the example above
        // since $getCurrentUser returns a promise resolved when auth is initialized,
        // we can simple return that here to ensure the controller waits for auth before
        // loading
        return simpleLogin.$getCurrentUser();
      }]
    }
  })
}]);

app.controller("HomeCtrl", ["currentUser", function(currentUser) {
  // currentUser (provided by resolve) will contain the 
  // authenticated user or null if not logged in
}]);
```

ui-router:

```
app.factory("User", ["$FirebaseObject", "$firebase", function($FirebaseObject, $firebase) {
  // create a new factory based on $FirebaseObject
  var UserFactory = $FirebaseObject.$extendFactory({
    // these methods exist on the prototype, so we can access the data using `this`
    getFullName: function() {
      return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }
  });

  return function(userId) {
    var ref = new Firebase("https://<your firebase>.firebaseio.com/users/").child(userId);

    // override the factory used by $firebase
    var sync = $firebase(ref, {objectFactory: UserFactory});

    return sync.$asObject(); // this will be an instance of UserFactory
  }
}]);
```